# Escaping the a tag with ::after

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some links that look like this:

```
<p class="links">
   <a>Link 1</a>
   <a>Link 2</a>
</p>

.links a::after {
content: " - ";
}
```

The problem is that the `::after` tag selects within the `a` tag and the `-` that I add to it changes color and style to match the link, like so:

```
<a>Link 1::after</a>
<a>Link 2::after</a>
```

How can I get it to look like this:

```
<a>Link 1</a>::after
<a>Link 2</a>::after
```

Comment: you can just reset the styles in the `.links a:after` selector

Comment: "The problem is that the ::after tag selects within the a tag" This is expected. [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) live within their parent elements, not outside of them.

Comment: You can't place the `::after` outside of the link, however you can override its styling to look how you want instead of inheriting the color and style of its parent.

Comment: Why don't you use `ul li` structure and use `::after` pseudo element on `li` instead of this structure which doesn't looks very logical for a list of links?

Comment: Thanks @volt, I guess I misinterpreted how the ::after tag worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your after selector, add the following attributes:

```
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
```